# DBA's say no to SQL Server DTC?

Tags: sql-server, nservicebus, distributed-transactions

I am trying to get our DBA's to enable DTC on a cluster of SQL Server 2005. Unfortunately they keep refusing. Their argument that they would need to set up a dedicated host for DTC (Could take months!!) as it is not a matter of ticking a few boxes. Is this true? How intrusive is DTC on a shared environment such as a SQL farm. Do I have an argument against this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ask me this in my course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to tone down the original response your 'DBA' team deserve!

In response to your questions:

Dedicated server - Not at all. Everywhere I've worked with clusters, the DTC service is installed when the cluster is commissioned. Typically it sits in its own resource group or within the cluster group. If in its own group its usually sits on whichever server is hosting the cluster group.

Intrusive? - Absolutely not. It should be installed when the cluster is created, as per MS best practice.

Do you have an argument? - You most certainly do. The links below should cover the why and how for getting it installed:

[MSDTC and SQL on a Cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlblog/msdtc-and-sql-server-on-a-cluster)

[Clustered SQL Server do's, dont's and basic warnings](https://web.archive.org/web/20150306050012/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/254321)

Answer (score 0):

DTC needs to be enabled and running on both sides of the connection.  In my organization, it took some research to figure out which four boxes to check and then some hand-holding to get those boxes checked on all db servers, all app servers and most laptops.  There's still a couple of hold-out developer laptops... but they're ok as long as they don't write. :)

You should have some driving scenario (such as an atomic multiple database write) to hit the DBA's over the head with.  Give them some time to guess at alternatives... then let them know that DTC is the only hammer for this kind of nail.

I'm unsure of the implications of DTC on a SQL farm.  I imagine the whole farm could get involved in the transaction if it involves enough data... which can't be a good thing.